# How to add jquery preload to slider?

Tags: jquery, preload

I have a series of jquery slideshows (html) which are loaded into my main.php. What I need is to add a very simple preload to the slideshow in order to prevent it start to slide the images unless the images are completely loaded. Should I preload each image or the entire "slideshow.html" ?.
This is the code of the slideshow.html:

```
<body>
 <div id="slideshowContent">
            <img src="images/slideshows/grafica/lisyx_1.png" alt="Lisyx"  class="active"/>
            <img src="images/slideshows/grafica/lisyx_2.png" alt="Lisyx" />
        </div>
</body>
```

The function for the slide:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshowContent IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshowContent IMG:last');

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshowContent IMG:first');
    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    slideshowInterval = setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing here is `you are firing` the `slideSwitch()` function on `doc ready`

instead you can add a class `.preload` (which will have a ajax loader image) to body or any of your page body element.

so you can try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').addClass('preload'); // <---on doc ready preload will be added
    $(window).load(function(){
    $('body').removeClass('preload'); // <---after window fully loaded preload will be removed
       slideshowInterval = setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000 );
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 except should be: slideshowInterval = setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000 );

Comment: I'm not an expert at all, any example of how the 'preload' class should look like?